# Function javascript not excute and i put it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try excute this function after the script charged.

```js
function sumar128() {
  //var Cantidadcc =$('#resulta128').text();
  document.getElementById('resulta128').textContent
  var tdElem = document.getElementById('resulta128');
  var Cantidadcc = tdElem.innerText | tdElem.textContent;
  var Pesocc = $('input[name="Peso128"]').val();
  var Preciocc = $('input[id="Precio128"]').val();
  var totalcc = Pesocc * Cantidadcc * Preciocc;
  var ncc = totalcc.toFixed(2);
  $('.result128').html(ncc);
}
sumar128();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class='a-row' align='center'>
  <td class='inputs' align='center'>
    <div onchange="changeit(128, 6, this);">7 : <input size="3" onkeyup="sumar128();" type="text" data-inputtype="CantidadS1286" value="0" /></div>
    <div onchange="changeit(128, 5, this);">8 : <input size="3" onkeyup="sumar128();" type="text" data-inputtype="CantidadS1285" value="0" /></div>
    <div onchange="changeit(128, 3, this);">9 : <input size="3" onkeyup="sumar128();" type="text" data-inputtype="CantidadS1283" value="3" /></div>
    <div onchange="changeit(128, 4, this);">
      9.5 : <input size="3" onkeyup="sumar128();" type="text" data-inputtype="CantidadS1284" value="1" /></div>
    <div onchange="changeit(128, 1, this);">10 : <input size="3" onkeyup="sumar128();" type="text" data-inputtype="CantidadS1281" value="33" /></div>
    <div onchange="changeit(128, 2, this);">11 : <input size="3" onkeyup="sumar128();" type="text" data-inputtype="CantidadS1282" value="2" /></div>
  </td>
  <td style='vertical-align:middle' class='result' id='resulta128'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Not apper anything in div result128 when do sumar128();

Comment: What does the developer console show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before call sumar128() function you should ensure that your [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) is loaded.
You can make it with [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   sumar128();
});
```

Or you can use pain JS for this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   sumar128();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Really work for this exposed script.

I use for this script but not work for these script.

```
<script>function sumar".$idPedido."(){
            //var Cantidadcc =$('#resulta".$idPedido."').text();
            document.getElementById ('resulta".$idPedido."').textContent
            var tdElem = document.getElementById ('resulta".$idPedido."');
            var Cantidadcc = tdElem.innerText | tdElem.textContent;
            var Pesocc = $('input[name=\"Peso".$idPedido."\"]').val();
            var Preciocc = $('input[id=\"Precio".$idPedido."\"]').val();
            var totalcc = Pesocc * Cantidadcc * Preciocc;
        var ncc = totalcc.toFixed(2);
        $('.result".$idPedido."').html(ncc);
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
   sumar".$idPedido."();
});
            
            
            </script>
```